# Как задать зажержку боту на отправку сообщений? Python telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, aiogram

Пытаюсь разбраться, как через функцию задать задержку в 3 секунды, после чего должно отправиться сообщение. Использую asyncio и по сути через ключевое слово await откладываю действие на время. Мне нужно сделать так: идет проверка в условном операторе, если значение истинно, то переходим в функцию, в ней будет задержка на 3 секунды и должно отправиться сообщение, но мне выдает в консоли `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`. Чего то не хватает? Или что то надо убрать?

```
if rand % 2 == 1:
    delay_time(message)

...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def delay_time(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "проверка выполнена!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ не заставил себя долго ждать, в самой функции нужно было убрать await вот тут `await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "проверка выполнена!")`, далее, чтобы правильно вызвать функцию, порылся в документации и написал так `asyncio.run(delay_time(message))` и вуаля, все работает :)

```
if rand % 2 == 1:
    asyncio.run(delay_time(message))

...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def delay_time(message):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "проверка выполнена!")
```